# Do 32-bit Programs Actually Use More Memory On 64-bit Operating Systems?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, cpu

When executing a 32-bit program on a 64-bit CPU, can we assume that the underlying hardware will use 32-bit values in memory and in the CPU registers to store an integer?

Given these setups:

- Intel i5 + Windows 32 bit + 32 bit application
- Intel i5 + Windows 64 bit + 32 bit application

Please explain the drawbacks of each setup. Would using the second one be less efficient because the CPU gets extra work to ignore halt of the register's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an x86_64 processor executes 32-bit code it is effectively running in i686 mode. This is all achieved in hardware so there is no performance penalty.

A user-space 32-bit program will be executed in "32 bit mode" whether the operating system is 32 bits or 64 bits so the behaviour should be identical.

The only potential drawback is that the program might need to dynamically link to some 32-bit libraries which are not installed by default on the 64-bit OS.  That sort of scenario is more common on Linux where it is much more common for programs to dynamically link to external libraries; the only example I can think of on Windows is if the program needs the Visual C++ runtime library then you would have to install the 32-bit version of that (possibly alongside the 64-bit version, if another program needed that). So in short you might have to install more stuff with a 64 bit set up.

Also the actual OS might consume more memory on a 64 bit setup, however one drawback of 32-bit system is that your entire system memory size is limited to 4GB (or practically about 3.5 GB due to some memory space being mapped to hardware).

Comment: That 32 bit mode, is it slower? I.E: re-building the program in 64-bit will make it faster? It should take more memory but I wonder how speed is affected. If it's the same, then why bother building in 64-bit if you got enough memory?

Comment: 64-bit mode has more registers available so presumably the compiler can emit more efficient code. Also any operations on numbers which are larger than 32-bits are going to be more efficient in 64-bit mode. This may or may not be significant, depending on the program and how much number crunching it does.

Answer (score 0):

64-bit Knowledge Base: [How much memory can an application access in Win32 and Win64?](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0036/)

Comment: I don't want to know how much you can access, I know you can only use 32-bit pointers by defaults (without bigmem I guess). I just wonder if when you put an integer in memory (mov) you end up writing a 64-bit value to memory somehow (since it may be faster for the CPU to do so), and if not, by how many orders of magnitude would the 32-bit operation be slower (still taking about a mov).